# How to randomly list JSON inside Flutter model?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a scrollable screen style app on TikTok. Each time you swipe, a word will come from the list in the Model.

Model:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

List<Map<String, Object?>> allWords = [
  {
    "ID": 0,
    "Word": "If you don't put your life on the line, you can't earn your life.",
    "Author": "Friedrich Schiller",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Word": "If you can dream it, you can do it.",
    "Author": "Friedrich Schiller",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Word":
        "We don't have to be smarter than others. We have to be more disciplined than others.",
    "Author": "Warren Buffett",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 4,
    "Word": "The harder the fight, the more honorable your victory!",
    "Author": "Thomas Paine",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "Word": "Work now, cry later.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 6,
    "Word":
        "Although everything in this life is difficult, it is never impossible.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 7,
    "Word": "Success is the sum of small efforts repeated every day.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 8,
    "Word":
        "Those who take risks you do not dare to take will live the life you want to live.",
    "Author": "Sokrates",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 9,
    "Word":
        "Failure will never catch me if my determination to succeed is strong enough!",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 10,
    "Word": "If you don't know how things are done, change it your way!",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 11,
    "Word":
        "People's biggest weakness is giving up. The surest rule of success is to always try one more time.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 12,
    "Word": "Quality is not an action, it is a habit.",
    "Author": "Aristo",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 13,
    "Word":
        "First ask yourself what will happen; then do whatever you need to do.",
    "Author": "Epiktetos",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 14,
    "Word":
        "Accept the challenges so that you can feel the enthusiasm of victory.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 15,
    "Word": "Life is 10% what happens to you and 90% how you respond to it.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 16,
    "Word":
        "You will be responsible for the end of your life, not the beginning.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 17,
    "Word":
        "Live as if you were living for the second time and misbehaved the first time.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 18,
    "Word":
        "If the road ahead is clear, you are most likely on someone else's path.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 19,
    "Word": "Only those who risk going too far see how far they can go.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 20,
    "Word":
        "The world breaks everyone, and some get stronger from their broken places.",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 21,
    "Word":
        "Do not cry for the setting sun; Decide what you will do when he is reborn.",
    "Author": "Dale Camegie",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 22,
    "Word":
        "You don't really need a miracle. You need to remember that you are a miracle.",
    "Author": "Tayfun Topaloğlu",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 23,
    "Word": "If you don't ask questions, you didn't listen!",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 24,
    "Word":
        "If you don't design your own life plan, you'll find yourself in someone else's plan. And do you know what they have planned for you?",
    "Author": "",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 25,
    "Word":
        "You have the power within you right now to do things you could never have imagined.",
    "Author": "Maxwell Maltz",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 26,
    "Word":
        "Anlaşılır olun! Kullanım kılavuzu gerektiren her ürün baştan hatalıdır.",
    "Author": "Elon Musk",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 27,
    "Word":
        "İşinizi tutkuyla yapın! İnsanlar tutkulu oldukları şeyin peşinden gitmeli. Bu bireyleri her şeyden daha çok mutlu eder.",
    "Author": "Elon Musk",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 28,
    "Word": "Do or die but never give up!",
    "Author": "Elon Musk",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 29,
    "Word":
        "Some people don't like change, but if the other alternative is disaster, you have to embrace change.",
    "Author": "Elon Musk",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 30,
    "Word":
        "If you wake up in the morning and think that the future will be better, it will be a bright day.",
    "Author": "Elon Musk",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 31,
    "Word":
        "When something is important enough, you do it even when the odds are not in your favour.",
    "Author": "Elon Musk",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 32,
    "Word":
        "Failure is an option here. If things don't fail, you're not innovating enough.",
    "Author": "Elon Musk",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 33,
    "Word":
        "Money can't buy what I value most in life. The most important resource we have in life is time.",
    "Author": "Steve Jobs",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 34,
    "Word":
        "If you do something and something good comes out, then you should try for something better without waiting too long.",
    "Author": "Steve Jobs",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 35,
    "Word":
        "I'm just as proud of the things we didn't do as the things we did, because innovation means no to thousands of ideas.",
    "Author": "Steve Jobs",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 36,
    "Word": "Rule #1: Never lose money. Rule 2: Never forget Rule 1.",
    "Author": "Warren Buffett",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 37,
    "Word":
        "It's always good to be with people in a better position than you, spend time with people who have better manners than you. In time you will find that you are like them",
    "Author": "Warren Buffett",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 38,
    "Word":
        "Whether it's a stocking or a stock, I buy it when the price drops.",
    "Author": "Warren Buffett",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 39,
    "Word": "It takes 20 years to build a reputation, 5 minutes to lose it!",
    "Author": "Warren Buffett",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 40,
    "Word":
        "If you double the number of experiments you do each year, you double your creativity.",
    "Author": "Jeff Bezos",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 41,
    "Word": "Life is too short to spend time with people who don't benefit.",
    "Author": "Jeff Bezos",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 42,
    "Word":
        "Don't show yourself less than you are. Everyone has a unique perspective they can bring to the world.",
    "Author": "Mark Zuckerberg",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 43,
    "Word":
        "The biggest risk is not taking any risks. In a truly rapidly changing world, the only strategy that fails is not taking risks.",
    "Author": "Mark Zuckerberg",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 44,
    "Word":
        "If things aren't breaking down, you're not moving fast enough. People learn by making mistakes.",
    "Author": "Mark Zuckerberg",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 45,
    "Word":
        "When you want to change something, you can't please everyone. If you please everyone, you won't be making enough progress.",
    "Author": "Mark Zuckerberg",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 46,
    "Word":
        "It's important for young entrepreneurs to be aware enough to know what they don't know.",
    "Author": "Mark Zuckerberg",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 47,
    "Word":
        "People don't care what is said about you. They don't even care what you say. They look at what you are building.",
    "Author": "Mark Zuckerberg",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 48,
    "Word":
        "If you don't give up, you still have a chance. And if you are small, you must rely on your brain rather than your strength and concentrate.'",
    "Author": "Jack Ma",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 49,
    "Word":
        "If we're a good team that knows what they want to do, one of us can beat ten of them.",
    "Author": "Jack Ma",
    "Image": "",
  },
  {
    "ID": 50,
    "Word":
        "If you haven't done anything crazy, you're not on the right track.",
    "Author": "Larry Page",
    "Image": "",
  },
];

class Words {
  final int iD;
  final String word;
  final String author;
  final String image;

  Words(
      {required this.iD,
      required this.author,
      required this.word,
      required this.image});

  factory Words.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) {
    return Words(
        iD: json['ID'] as int,
        author: json['Author'] as String,
        word: json['Word'] as String,
        image: json["Image"] as String);
  }

  factory Words.getRandomWord() {
    math.Random random = math.Random();
    return Words.fromJson(allWords[random.nextInt(allWords.length - 1)]);
  }
}
```

`HomePage.dart`:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:teenmotivation/Models/Words.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
Words words = Words.getRandomWord();

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: // I don't know what to write here
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My goal is to make a scrollable screen system like TikTok. Each screen will have a different word. I want to place it in `children` by fetching random mention from the JSON in the model. How can I do that?

Thanks for help.

Comment: are you looking to implement pagination to the list

Comment: Why don't you use the item builder field instead of the children

Comment: @dere yonas yes.

Comment: @THEODORE How can I do it? Can you post a sample code as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should use following:

```
PageView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return // your BuildItemWidget and a random word. Do not pay attention to index
      },
    )
```

If `PageView.builder` has not itemCount, it makes itself infinity scroll.